# Is a symmetric matrix diagonalizable if it is not symmetric in the standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is a symmetric matrix diagonalizable if it is not symmetric in the standard basis?

The reason is because most of the theorems I have seen regarding the diagonalizability of symmetric matrices assumes we are working with the standard basis, but what if we are working with a non-orthogonal basis (assume standard inner product) such that if we change it back to the standard basis, the matrix is no longer symmetric.

Or to put it terms of operator, the matrix does not represent a normal or not a self adjoint operator, so we can not apply the real or complex spectral theorem.

Comment: Yes; the spectral theorem can be stated with independence of bases and therefore it applies to any base, not necessarily the standard one